# Constructor for wrapper around std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to write a wrapper class with a data member std::vector. How should my class's default constructor look like so that I can do the following without getting out of range error:

```
Wrapper W;
W[0] = value;  //overloaded index operator, forwards to the vector
```

Comment: Perhaps the constructor should do nothing, and instead `operator[]` should check the size and `resize()` the vector to ensure `i` is in range (beware of invalidating previous references)? Otherwise, it's a complete guess how big the vector should be, so no one can really say what your default constructor should look like.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I meant W[0] and not W[i].

Comment: If all you want is `W[0]`, then the constructor could be `Wrapper() : m_vector(1) {}`

Comment: Thet's a very big typo

Comment: @john Living up to my username, aren't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize the vector before accessing the element:

```
// in the class definition
std::vector vec;

T &operator[](typename std::vector<T>::size_type idx)
{
    if (idx >= vec.size()) {
        vec.resize(idx + 1);
    }

    return vec[idx];
}
```

**Edit:** now `0` instead of `i`, that's a huge typo. In that case, you can just construct a vector of size 1 in-place:

```
std::vector<T> vec = std::vector<T>(1);

public:
T &operator[](typename std::vector<T>::size_type idx)
{
    return vec[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor is irrelevant. Your `operator []` needs to check whether the supplied index is out of range and make the vector bigger as necessary. (I'm assuming here that "returns reference to the `vector<T>`" is a typo and you want to forward to the vector's `operator[]` at some point).